# Add and Invoke a VBA Sub on Visio Macro using C#

Tags: c#, vba, visio

I need to include a series of VBA Macro subprocesses to a Visio document using C# and invoke one of them after completion.

I'm currently able to add the macro to the Visio file, but I cannot invoke this recently inserted `Sub`:

```
//...
using Office = Microsoft.Office.Core;
using VBA = Microsoft.Vbe.Interop;
using Visio = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio;
//...
Visio.Application vsApp  vsApp = new Visio.Application();
Visio.Document doc = vsApp.Documents.Open("filepath");
vsApp.Visible = true;
VBA.VBComponent oModule = doc.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(VBA.vbext_ComponentType.vbext_ct_StdModule);
String sCode =
    "sub VBAMacro()\r\n" +
    "   msgbox \"VBA Macro called\"\r\n" +
    "end sub";
    // Add the VBA macro to the new code module.
oModule.CodeModule.AddFromString(sCode);

//HOW TO INVOKE VBAMacro ??

doc.Close();
vsApp.Quit();
```

What do I need to do in order to invoke `VBAMacro`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visio doesn't have a `Run` method on the Application object, but it does have `Document.ExecuteLine`:

```
'Executes the macro (procedure without an argument) named "SomeMacro" 
 'that is in some module of the Visual Basic project of ThisDocument. 
 ThisDocument.ExecuteLine("SomeMacro") 

 'Executes the procedure named SomeProcedure and passes it 3 arguments. 
 ThisDocument.ExecuteLine("SomeProcedure 1, 2, 3") 

 'Same as previous example, but procedure name qualified 
 'with module name. 
 ThisDocument.ExecuteLine("Module1.SomeProcedure 1, 2, 3") 

 'Shows the form UserForm1. 
 ThisDocument.ExecuteLine("UserForm1.Show") 

 'Prints "some string" to the Immediate window. 
 ThisDocument.ExecuteLine("Debug.Print ""some string""") 

 'Prints number of open documents to the Immediate window. 
 ThisDocument.ExecuteLine("Debug.Print Documents.Count") 

 'Tells ThisDocument to save itself. 
 ThisDocument.ExecuteLine("ThisDocument.Save")
```

From: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff765100(v=office.15).aspx